# Upload multiple attachments to the same task via api

Tags: ruby, asana, asana-api

Is it actually possible to upload multiple attachments to the same task with a single request?

My current code is this:

```
uri = URI "#{ASANA_ENDPOINT}/tasks/#{asana_id}/attachments"
connection = create_connection
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri

Dir.entries(ATTACHMENT_FOLDER).reject { |entry| ['.', '..'].include?(entry) }.each do |entry|
  form_data = [['file', File.open("#{attachment_folder}/#{entry}"), { filename: entry }]]
  request.set_form form_data, 'multipart/form-data'
  request['Authorization'] = AUTHORIZATION_HEADER

  response = connection.request request
end
```

So I send a request to asana for each attach in the attachment folder. And it works.

But I'd like to make one request where file parameter will contain all attachments - is it possible?

Comment: yes, javascript is your friend in this case

Comment: Why javascript?

I try to do it from a ruby script via Net::HTTP::Post.new. It works well for one attachment.

But it does not work when trying to add two attachments to 'file' params. Seems to me that 'file' param allows only one attachment. Maybe we need 'files[]' params for two or more attachments. But there's no such parameter in Asana API.

Comment: Why not to put yr code and write some text. What issue are you facing and where ?